# Trying to compare "parts of speech" tags of two files and print the matched tags in a separate file

Tags: perl

I am trying to code a perl program to compare the "parts of speech" tags of two text files and print the matched tags along with the corresponding words in a separate file in Windows.

```
File1:
boy N
went V
loves V
girl N
File2:
boy N
swims V
girl N
loves V
```

The expected output:
    boy N N
    girl N N
    loves V V

The columns are separated by tabs. The coding I did so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'file1.txt';
open(my $fh, $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename'";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "$row\n";
}
my $tagfile = 'file2.txt';
open(my $tg, $tagfile)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename'";
while (my $row = <$tg>) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
    }
```

Comment: May we see your Perl code so far? What problem are you having? What is "POS"?

Comment: As it stands it is unclear what you're actually asking. We don't know what "POS" is, nor do we know what your algorithm is. However for manipulating tab separated fields, I'd suggest what you want is a combination of `split` and a hash.

Comment: POS stands for Parts of speech which are basically the nouns, verbs etc.i am trying to compare two text files  with names and associated tags on them and return the words which are common on both the files on a separate file.
my $filename = 'bangla_train.txt';
open(my $fh, $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename'";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "$row\n";
}
my $tagfile = 'file1.txt';
open(my $tg, $tagfile)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename'";
while (my $row = <$tg>) {
 chomp $row;
 print "$row\n";
 } This coding is just reading and printing both the files.

Comment: You need to [edit] the question by clicking the [[edit]] link below the question.

Comment: I'm voting to put on hold at present, but if the question closes and you are able to edit in your code, I'll happily cast a reopen vote.

Comment: Are you trying to match "N"/"V"? (I assume noun/verb) or just the presence of word in the files?

Comment: I am trying to match the words with the same tags (Nouns/Verbs) and print them in a separate file. SO, the program should take a word from file A, search it in file B, If both the word and the corresponding tags match then print them in file c.

Comment: Your current code doesn't do any comparisons, it simply prints the contents of each file.  No attempt is made to compare anything.

Comment: Yes thats what I could execute correctly till now. I am trying to edit the program with different pattern matching codes but nothing is giving a valid output.

Comment: I have read these questions and tried to help with them: [*Separating an Output with a Tab / Space : Perl*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974486/separating-an-output-with-a-tab-space-perl), [*Search for words ending with 'ing' from a text file in perl*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905961/search-for-words-ending-with-ing-from-a-text-file-in-perl), [*Trying to compare "parts of speech" tags of two files and print the matched tags in a separate file*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890276/trying-to-compare-parts-of-speech-tags-of-two-files-and-print-the-matched-tags)

Comment: They are all very similar questions, and it is looking like you're not learning anything from the answers that we give you. You won't learn Perl by getting others to solve your problems, only by *learning the Perl language*. We can't help with that here, but [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/) is an excellent resource. You must start learning properly instead of making imaginary progress by using other people's effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really unclear what you're asking for. But I think this is close.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

my %words; # Keep details of the words
while (<>) { # Read all input files a line at a time
  chomp;
  my ($word, $pos) = split;
  $words{$ARGV}{$word}{$pos}++;

  # If we're processing file1 then don't look for a match
  next if $ARGV eq $file1;

  if (exists $words{$file1}{$word}{$pos}) {
     print join(' ', $word, ($pos) x 2), "\n";
  }
}
```

Running it like this:

```
./pos file1 file2
```

Gives:

```
boy N N
girl N N
loves V V
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am using the Perl version 5.8.8. So, the coding is giving compilation errors due to different version of Perl. Can you please let me know how should I do the coding in v5.8.8.

Comment: @Nandini143, Try removing the `use 5.010;` line and change this line: `say join ' ', $word, ($pos) x 2;` to `print join ' ', $word, ($pos) x 2; print "\n";`

Comment: Yes, remove the `use 5.010` and convert the `say` statement to use `print` instead. But why are you using such an old and unsupported version of Perl?

Comment: At which point the question becomes "why are you using the system Perl?" :-)

Comment: Thank you @DaveCross The code is running perfectly and giving the expected output. However, I am getting two command line errors while executing the program and which reads "Use of uninitialized value in join or string at test6.pl line 16, <> line 21598" and "Use of uninitialized value in hash element at test6.pl line 10, <> line 2159". Do you have any ideas how can I fix them.

Comment: You probably need to replace that line with `if (exists $words{$file1} && exists $words{$file1}{$word} && exists $words{$file1}{$pos})`. Which is annoying.

Comment: If my answer is useful, then please vote it up or accept it.

Comment: Just to correct myself, the code is giving partial output, and the values are correct. But, the program breaks due to the aforementioned errors.

Comment: They aren't errors, they are warnings. They won't stop the program working. If the program isn't working as you want it to, that's probably because I'm guessing at most of your requirements.

Comment: The program does works but it does not give the complete output and the values are missing from the output and some values are duplicate  and modifying the code as you suggested dint work as well. Hard luck!

Comment: Can you provide test data that demonstrates the problems? Perhaps you could try debugging the code and fixing the problem yourself. I've given you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first off what you want is a [`hash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

You need to:

- read the first file, split it into "word" and "pos".
- save it in a hash
- read the second file, split each line into "word" and "pos".
- compare it to the hash you populated, and check it matches.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

#declare our hash:

my %pos_for;


#open the first file
my $filename = 'file1.txt';
open( my $fh, '<', $filename ) or die "Could not open file '$filename'";

while (<$fh>) {
    #remove linefeed from this line.
    #note - both chomp and split default to using $_ which is defined by the while loop.
    chomp;

    #split it on whitespace.
    my ( $word, $pos ) = split;

    #record this value in the hash %pos_for
    $pos_for{$word} = $pos;
}
close($fh);

#process second file:

my $tagfile = 'file2.txt';
open( my $tg, '<', $tagfile ) or die "Could not open file '$filename'";
while (<$tg>) {

    #remove linefeed from this line.
    chomp;

    #split it on whitespace.
    my ( $word, $pos ) = split;

    #check if this word was in the other file
    if (defined $pos_for{$word}
        #and that it's the same "pos" value.
        and $pos_for{$word} eq $pos
        )
    {
        print "$word $pos\n";
    }
}
close($tg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the coding is giving error in the use of hash element for both the files during execution. So,how should I rectify this error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know - I don't have enough detail.